# Does a SOAP client need to run on a web service?

Tags: web-services, soap, webserver

I'm new to SOAP.
I would like to understand if a SOAP client can run without a webserver ( like only JavaSE with JAXB lib ) or not

Answer (score 0):

HTTP clients make requests *to* HTTP servers.

They only need to part of an HTTP server if their user interface is also designed to be accessed over HTTP.